# FlutterFlow App that Sends JSON + File to Google App Script Securely

Tags: flutterflow

What is the best way to securely send files and JSON data from a FlutterFlow app to a Google App Script that will use the JSON data to determine where to save the files?

If I use a "multipart" call for it, that disables the "private API call" option, which sounds insecure to me. However, if I enable "private API call" I have no way to send actual files. I can save the files to firebase/firestore and it will return the URL of the file, but I don't know how I would get a password-protected secure file from Firebase to Google App Script, even if I have the URL.